# Altering JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES

Tags: database, oracle, dbms-scheduler, dbms-job

Does altering the JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES to 0 on an Oracle DB block the Oracle jobs from being scheduled too?

I found in http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96521/jobq.htm some information about it, principally, the following:

> The JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES initialization
>   parameter controls whether a
>   coordinator job queue process is
>   started by an instance. If this
>   parameter is set to 0, no coordinator
>   job queue process is started at
>   database startup, and consequently no
>   job queue jobs are executed. The
>   JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES initialization
>   parameter also specifies the maximum
>   number of Jnnn processes that can
>   concurrently run on an instance. The
>   maximum number of processes that can
>   be specified is 1000.

However, I am uncertain what the "coordinator job queue" represents in the grand scheme of things.

Thank you very much in advance for your timely responses.

Comment: job_queue_processes has some history: http://ronr.blogspot.com/2009/09/jobqueueprocesses-and-dbmsscheduler.html Lots of changes over time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Prior to 11.2, if you set `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` to 0, no job scheduled via `DBMS_JOB` will be executed.  That parameter does not affect jobs scheduled via the `DBMS_SCHEDULER` package.  If by "Oracle jobs" you are referring to things like the background job in 10g and later that automatically gathers statistics on objects with missing or stale statistics, those are `DBMS_SCHEDULER` jobs that would be unaffected by `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES`.

Starting in 11.2, that [changed and JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES began to affect DBMS_SECHEDULER.](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17222/changes.htm#UPGRD12499)  The default value also changed from 0 to 1000 and it was made a non-basic initialization parameter.

Comment: DBMS_SCHEDULER is affected by this parameter at least it is in 11.2.  See http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17110/initparams108.htm#REFRN10077 Where it says, "DBMS_JOB and Oracle Scheduler share the same job coordinator and job slaves, and they are both controlled by the JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES parameter."

Comment: @Leigh- Good catch, that's new in 11.2

Comment: +1 Thanks for the clarification; I wasn't sure if it changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle EBS, Oracle recommends value for `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` be 10.